# How to execute a function for each variable in the loop?

Tags: php

What I'm trying to do is to execute the function I made for each variable in the loop; like this:

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= 3; $i++) {
  foreach($i as $y){
    $test = my_func('test function number:'.$y');
  }
}
```

and the result should be something like this:

```
test function number:1
test function number:2
test function number:3
```

NOT

```
test function number:123
```

**UPDATE:**
The function is actually base on URLs and not displaying and what i want is that function to execute the URL each time based on another `$i` in the case above up to `3` and the `for` statement is giving me the `$i=4` and not `$i=1` `$i=2` and `$i=3` ... so on

**UPDATE 2**

i just tried this:

```
$i = range(1,5);
foreach($i as $page){
$test = my_func('http://www.test.com/cars/page'.$page);
}
```

and the result was for the page `http://www.test.com/cars/page5`.... any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are overwriting `$test` in each run, you get only the 4 as "output" if you echo `$test` *afterwards*.

Either echo *inside* the loop:

```
function my_func($val) { return $val; }

for ($i = 1; $i <= 3; $i++) {
  echo my_func('test function number: ' . $i);
}
```

or put the output into an array and iterate over that or just `implode` it later:

```
function my_func($val) { return $val; }

$text = array();
for ($i = 1; $i <= 3; $i++) {
  $text[] = my_func('test function number: ' . $i);
}
echo implode(' - ', $text);
```

---

You seem to be lacking the very basics of how to handle variables and functions in PHP - so it might be time for some begginer tutorials.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, now i can insert it into the table in DB, thanks again! although i really can't understand why ppl are down-voting this, i had a problem and i posted it,this is how it should work, not down-voting for nothing....

Answer (score -1):

There's no need to use foreach, just use the `for` loop. Like this:

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= 3; $i++) {
    $test = my_func('test function number: '. $i);
}
```

This may help :)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but actually this is giving me the `$i=4` and i want the `$i` to be each time another value up to `3` like `$i=1` `$i=2` `$i=3`, get it ?

Comment: It's physically impossible for `$i` to be equal to 4 in starky's answer.  (although there is a stray single quote that needs removing). You must be doing something you're not posting.

Comment: @Tim see my update2 please

Comment: @Tim basically i want the function to re-run  as long as there's `$i`

Comment: Why minus if he didn't exactly explained what he wanted. No doubt.

Answer (score -1):

If you have an array of values you can use the function **array_walk**.

See: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php

```
<?php
$fruits = array("d" => "lemon", "a" => "orange", "b" => "banana", "c" => "apple");

function test_alter(&$item1, $key, $prefix)
{
    $item1 = "$prefix: $item1";
}

function test_print($item2, $key)
{
    echo "$key. $item2<br />\n";
}

echo "Before ...:\n";
array_walk($fruits, 'test_print');

array_walk($fruits, 'test_alter', 'fruit');
echo "... and after:\n";

array_walk($fruits, 'test_print');
?>
```

The above example will output:

```
Before ...:

d. lemon
a. orange
b. banana
c. apple

... and after:

d. fruit: lemon
a. fruit: orange
b. fruit: banana
c. fruit: apple
```